# Mayúsculas en cin

Tags: c++

> Tengo una pregunta, como hago para que al momento de leer un string, el programa se ejecute sin importar si el dato ingresado es en mayúsculas o minúsculas?

Por ejemplo

`while(var=="ok"){ cin>>ok; }`

Cómo hago para poder ingresar un OK y que aún así se ejecute? Solo me deja ejecutarlo si escribo específicamente en minúsculas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opcion es ir probando para cada combinacion de letras en mayuscula y
minuscula. El unico problema es que rapidamente se puede volver tedioso.

La otra opcion seria convertir el string que te den a minusculas, y solo
comparar con letras minusculas.

Puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

static std::string to_lower_case(std::string s) {
    // Si usas la librería estándar, puedes remplazar el for completo por una
    // linea de codigo
    //
    // std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), std::tolower);
    //
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        s[i] = static_cast<char>(std::tolower(s[i]));
    }
    return s;
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char * /*argv*/[]) {
    std::string ok = "ok";
    while (to_lower_case(ok) == "ok") {
        std::cin >> ok;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Esta variante acepta todas dentro de:

```
ok
OK
Ok
oK
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar el operador logico OR, `||`. este operador lógico valida dos sentencias y si alguna de las dos es verdadera se ejecuta

```
while(var=="ok" || var == "OK"){ cin>>ok; }
```